# How not to overwrite the data in the db

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem with entering data in the database (Couch / Pouch).
Basically I have a form through which I pass the values ​​entered to a function that performs a put in the database, thus entering the data.
The problem is that if by chance one of these fields from the form is left empty, once the put is executed this field is deleted from the database.

So for example, if I have the FirstName: "NameUser" field in the db, and going to compile the form nothing is entered in the field corresponding to FirstName, the value FirstName and "NameUser" are deleted from the db.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you all.

```
//.....
.then(response => {
  let utente = response.docs[0];
    utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.FirstName;
    utente.Person.LastName = this.state.LastName;
    utente.Person.City = this.state.City;
    utente.Person.Address = this.state.Address;
    return global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);  
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
}) }

render() {
return (
<View style={style.container}>
  <View style={style.page}>
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView>

      <View style={style.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={style.inputs}
          placeholder="Name"
          placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
          keyboardType="default"
          underlineColorAndroid="grey"
          onChangeText={FirstName =>
            this.setState({ FirstName })
          }
        />
      </View>

      <View style={style.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={style.inputs}
          placeholder="Surname"
          placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
          keyboardType="default"
          underlineColorAndroid="grey"
          onChangeText={LastName => 
            this.setState({ LastName })}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={style.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={style.inputs}
          placeholder="City"
          placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
          keyboardType="default"
          underlineColorAndroid="grey"
          onChangeText={City => this.setState({ City })}
        />
      </View>
      {/*
      <View style={style.inputContainer}>

      </View>
        */}
      <View style={style.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={style.inputs}
          placeholder="Address"
          placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
          keyboardType="default"
          underlineColorAndroid="grey"
          onChangeText={Address => this.setState({ Address })}
        />
        <View style={style.footer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => this.findUtente(this.props.cf)}
          >
            <Text>Save</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I would recommend adding the attribute defaultValue = "Name" so at least something is entered and you can get the data.  Can always clean it up afterward.

Comment: @JMeyerDataScience So for every field in the form i should add this attribute?? :)

Comment: My problem is that I can't write the default values. They should be dependent from the db informations